# Onion hostname for VPS

Tags: vps

I have hidden service with some hostname for it like eg: lbksdvcjhsdvcjhsdvc.onion

Can I set-up this hostname also for my VPS?
I tried but it can't resolve name for onion domain.
So is there a chance that I can set up correct my VPS hostname like the same for my hidden service?

eg. VPS hostname home.com www hostname home.com
VSP hostname lbksdvcjhsdvcjhsdvc.onion www lbksdvcjhsdvcjhsdvc.onion

what I need to torify to properly resolve domain name for VPS with onion address?

I hope this question make sense :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it makes, you're adding a corresponding entry in `/etc/hosts` and just making this :

1. Add an **additional localhost interface** lo0:0 with 127.0.1.1/24 subnet
2. Modify your lo0 **to shorter scope** 127.0.0.1/24 - they **must not intersect/interfere** with an interface from pt.1
3. Make tor bind it's DNS to 127.0.0.**2**:53
4. Install ISC Bind and tie it to 127.0.0.**1**:53
5. Tell bind to resolve dot-onion(**.onion**) addresses via 127.0.0.**2** like this:

   ```
   zone "onion" {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders {
        127.0.0.2;
    };
   ```

in your named.conf right **inside the curlies({})** after the default zones

6. Use your local named to resolve all the URL's you need, including dot-onion

=)